# How To Loop Array List In Postegress D

Tags: database, postgresql, stored-procedures

I Want to Loop Through A Array list in Postegres Sql

here is my query

```
do $$
    declare 
    jsn JSONB;
    j JSONB;
    arj JSONB[];
    begin
        jsn = to_jsonb('{"lst" : [{"a":"1"}, {"b":"2"}]'::TEXT);
        arj = jsn->>'lst';
        FOREACH j IN ARRAY arj LOOP
              SELECT j;
        END LOOP;
    end;
$$;
```

But When I Run This I am Getting This Error

```
ERROR:  FOREACH expression must not be null
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 9 at FOREACH over array
SQL state: 22004
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?  It's unlikely that a loop is the best way to accomplish it.  You are also confusing jsonb arrays with postgres arrays.  You don't have an array of jsonb types, you have 1 jsonb element that happens to be an array.

Comment: I have a json object and there is list inside a that object so i want to loop all the items from that list how can i implement it ? any suggestions@Jeremy

Comment: Please edit your question and show the result you are trying to get.  Please don't just describe it, write out the actual result that you want.